# Loading images as base64 calls from Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I am trying to implement a small photo show via a django webserver. Below you can find the javascript code that loads the pictures into the images array and changes the images every x miliseconds. It works if I only load one picture (without the loop) from my django server but it stops working with any kind of loop.

I would love to know why it does not work this way and would be more than happy to receive some other feedback about code improvements. I am not very familiar with ajax calls yet.

Moreover: Django Templates Engine provides a easy way to simplify urls used in the templates. Is there a way to use the `{{% url %}}` tag inside a .js File as well?

```
window.images = [];
window.current = 0;
window.imageCount = 2;


function loadImages(){
    for(var i = 0; i < window.imageCount; i++){
        loadNextImage(i);
    }
    showImage();
}

function loadNextImage(i) {
    // https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/XMLHttpRequest/
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            window.images.push("data:image/jpeg;base64," + xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open('GET', "http://127.0.0.1:8000/mirror/"+i);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

function showImage() {
    if(window.current >= window.imageCount){
        window.current = 0;
    }
    alert("current window count = "+ window.current);
    document.getElementById('imgshow').src = window.images[window.current];
    window.current = window.current + 1;
    setTimeout(showImage, 50000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct problem you are encountering is because `XMLHttpRequest` is **Asynchronous** and you are dealing with a race condition. Here is what your code now is doing:

1. Start a loop and tell the browser to que 2 `XMLHttpRequests`.
2. Perform the showImage method (even though we have no idea if those 2 AJAX Requests above have returned yet.)
3. An exception is thrown at this line: `document.getElementById('imgshow').src = window.images[window.current];` because `window.images` is empty.
4. `setTimeout(showImage, 50000);` is never executed because of the exception at step 3.

Moving the `setTimeout` above the `document.getElementById('imgshow').src = window.images[window.current];` line might work. However, this **is a bad idea.**

One solution would be to remove the loop at all, and lazy load the images (only load them once they are needed) as seen below:

```js
window.images = [];
window.current = 0;
window.imageCount = 2;

function loadNextImage(i, callback) {
    // https://wiki.selfhtml.org/wiki/JavaScript/XMLHttpRequest/
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            window.images.push("data:image/jpeg;base64," + xmlhttp.responseText);
            callback.call();
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open('GET', "http://127.0.0.1:8000/mirror/"+i);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}

// Increments the image counter and loads the image if needed.
function stepImage() {
    // If we have reached the end of the images, restart.
    if(window.current >= window.imageCount){
        window.current = 0;
    }    
    // Make sure that the image is loaded in the images array,
    // if not, load the image, then show it.
    if(window.images.length <= window.current) {
        loadNextImage(window.current, showImage);
    }    
    // If it's already loaded, just show it.
    else showImage();
}

// Displays an image onto the page.
function showImage() {
  document.getElementById('imgshow').src = window.images[window.current];
  // The counter is not incremented until the image is shown!
  window.current++;
}

// Set a timer to render future images.
setInterval(stepImage, 3000);

// Render the first image.
stepImage();
```

```html
<img id="imgshow" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support! It works now. Your way to handle asynchronous activities reads out very smooth. This will help me alot to improve my quality of js code. I was not aware of the exception though. :)